# Azure DevOpsのWikiで相互参照を使う方法

Tags: azure, markdown, pandoc

#### 概要

Azure DevOpsのWikiページで画像や表などを参照するときに、相互参照を利用して参照番号を自動で割り振るようにするにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか?

#### 詳細

素の状態のMD記法で相互参照を記述することはできませんが、ローカル環境でPDF出力する際などにはpandoc-crossrefを使うなどの方法があります。
これをAzure DevOpsで実現する方法はありますでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Reposおよび、Project Wikiで扱えるのは素のWikiのみのはずなので、Pandocのようなポストプロセッサーを通して、PDFにしていただくしかないと思います。